# Запрос для поиска месяца с наибольшим количеством выплат

Tags: sql

Есть некая таблица с датами выплат и суммами, в каждом месяце разное количество выплат. Как найти месяц с большим количеством выплат?

```
pers    dat     summa   flag
1   01.09.2010  10000   1
3   01.10.2010  2500    1
9   01.10.2010  2500    1
12  01.10.2010  3100    1
7   01.10.2010  3300    1
8   01.10.2010  3300    0
4   12.10.2010  4500    0
2   12.10.2010  4500    0
18  12.10.2010  4000    1
25  12.10.2010  3500    1
19  18.10.2010  700     1
1   18.10.2010  700     1
3   18.10.2010  900     0
9   18.10.2010  1010    1
7   18.10.2010  1050    0
8   18.10.2010  700     1
4   27.10.2010  1050    1
18  28.10.2010  2500    1
25  28.10.2010  2500    1
19  28.10.2010  3000    1
5   30.10.2010  3050    0
40  30.10.2010  1800    0
1   30.10.2010  12000   1
3   30.10.2010  6000    1
9   02.11.2010  7500    1
7   02.11.2010  4000    1
8   02.11.2010  9500    1
4   05.11.2010  7750    1
2   05.11.2010  4500    1
18  05.11.2010  4900    0
25  05.11.2010  8100    1
5   05.11.2010  3500    0
33  05.11.2010  4010    1
8   11.11.2010  3300    0
4   12.11.2010  9500    0
2   12.11.2010  4900    0
18  12.11.2010  4000    1
25  12.11.2010  2400    1
19  18.11.2010  890     1
1   18.11.2010  660     1
3   18.11.2010  840     0
9   18.11.2010  950     1
7   18.11.2010  1090    0
9   18.11.2010  1450    1
7   18.11.2010  1800    0
8   18.11.2010  150     1
4   27.11.2010  900     1
18  28.11.2010  2400    1
25  28.11.2010  2500    1
19  28.11.2010  3300    1
5   30.11.2010  2800    0
40  30.11.2010  1800    0
1   30.11.2010  11050   1
1   30.11.2010  7480    0
9   02.12.2011  4820    1
7   02.12.2011  3350    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
SELECT year, month
FROM
  (
    SELECT year, month, sum(flag) AS cnt
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          DATEPART(yyyy, date) AS year,
          DATEPART(mm, date) AS month,
          flag
        FROM table
      ) y_m
    GROUP BY year, month
  ) all,
  (
    SELECT max(cnt)
    FROM (
      SELECT year, month, sum(flag) AS cnt
      FROM
        (
          SELECT
            DATEPART(yyyy, date) AS year,
            DATEPART(mm, date) AS month,
            flag
          FROM table
        ) y_m
      GROUP BY year, month
    ) tbl
  ) max
WHERE all.cnt = max.cnt
```

либо

```
SELECT TOP 1 year, month, SUM(flag) AS cnt
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      DATEPART(yyyy, date) AS year,
      DATEPART(mm, date) AS month,
      flag
    FROM table
  ) y_m
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY cnt
```

Comment: count - считает количество записей, а не сумму ;)

Comment: а где сказано про сумму??? в условии этого нет

Comment: сумму трогать не надо просто надо вывести все даты того месяца в котором было больше всего flag.

Comment: Если нужен любой ( гипотетически их может быть несколько ) месяц с максимальным кол-вом, то вам подойдёт вариант @renegator. <br>
Если все - то мой.

Comment: обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 year, month, COUNT(*)
FROM [table]
GROUP BY year, month
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял:

```
select *  from #bla
join
(select CONVERT(char(7),dat,102) ym from #bla group by CONVERT(char(7),dat,102)
having SUM(flag)>=all(select SUM(flag) from #bla group by CONVERT(char(7),dat,102)) 
)X
on CONVERT(char(7),dat,102) = ym
```

Какая СУБД не скажу. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select month, sum(salary) from table  
group by month
```

выведет все месяца и колонку со всеми выплатами за каждый месяц

```
select month, max(salary) from (
 select month, sum(salary) from table  
    group by month
)
```

а так должно вывести максимальное значение, если не ошибаюсь

Comment: ошибаетесь, month будет любым месяцем

Comment: ну добавить - `order by max desc limit 1`

Comment: нет, я же делаю group by month - в первом запросе они будут уникальные

Comment: имеется в виду, что `month` и `salary`, скорее всего, будут от разных строк<br>
( `month` - от последней, `salary` - от максимальной )